# Select records without category in many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a db with some products, they can be "tagged" with many categories. Some products have not an assigned category and I need to find them. Ineed to find records without category. I have created this tables:

**ITEMS**

```
+----+------+
| ID | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 | qwe  |
|  2 | asw  |
|  3 | wgr  |
+----+------+
```

**CATEGORIES**

```
+----+----------+
| ID | Category |
+----+----------+
|  1 | xxx      |
|  2 | yyy      |
+----+----------+
```

**RELATIONSHIP**

```
+---------+--------+
| id_item | id_cat |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       2 |      1 |
+---------+--------+
```

This is the (not working) query:

```
SELECT item.id COUNT(relationship.id_item) AS n
FROM item
JOIN relationships GROUP
BY relationships .n
WHERE item.id = relationships.id_item
AND relationships.n =0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use subquery with NOT IN clause

```
SELECT i.id
FROM item i
WHERE i.id NOT IN ( SELECT r.id_item
    FROM RELATIONSHIP r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a left join and then find the ones that don't match:

```
SELECT i.id, COUNT(relationship.id_item) AS n
FROM item i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     relationships r
     on i.id = r.id_item
WHERE r.id_item is null;
```